# Azure Recovery Services vault for DPM - Change to Locally Redundant

Tags: azure-storage, dpm

I'm using azure online backup vault for DPM long term retention. We're using about 14TB of Azure Geo redundant space.

I want to change the redundancy from Geo to Local, but it's greyed out. Is there a way to change it? This is because our usage forecast for DPM backup data was much lower than what is actually being used so its costing to much.

If this is not possible, Is there a way to migrate the complete Geo Redundant Vault to a Local Vault or the new Recovery Services vault?
Thanks Jon

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After an item has been registered to the vault, the storage redundancy option is locked and cannot be modified. For more detailed information, please refer to [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-configure-vault-classic).

[image]
It seems that It does not enable us to move protected items from an existing backup vault with Geo- redundant to another one new backup vault with locally-redundant. I recommend that you could create a new backup vault with locally-redundant and backup your DPM servers.